# Ansible - appending file content by cat command

Tags: ansible

I am downloading a file with some text and I want to attach this text to another file.

After download inet_licence_5 file on localhost. stage file is on localhost too.

This work fine:

```
cat ./inet_licence_5 >> ./stage
```

Unfortunately, in ansible, it does not work.

```
- name: Append to ./stage
  command: cat ./inet_licence_5 >> ./stage
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Error:

```
TASK [Append to ./stage] *******************************
fatal: [my -> 127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": 
["cat", "./inet_licence_5", ">>", "./stage"], "delta": 
"0:00:00.001814", "end": "2019-05-28 11:55:22.766532", "failed": 
true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-28 11:55:22.764718", "stderr": 
"cat: '>>': No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["cat: '>>': 
No such file or directory"], "stdout": "asdasd", "stdout_lines": 
["asdasd"]}
```

Strange because I'm doing this job in the main location.

```
$ ls
base  inet_licence_5 playbook1.yml
$ ansible-playbook playbook1.yml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For odd reason you assume your working directory is the same when running Ansible as it you would be when trying from shell. This is not true (you can always verify by running i.e. `pwd` as `command` and check the output). So you need to either specify full paths in your command arguments or use `chdir` to ensure you are really in the right directory (docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/command_module.html)

**EDIT**

Seems I overlooked that part from linked docs:

> The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not work

so you need to go other way about that as ordinary redirection won't simply work in current approach. I'd use  [shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) to run commands on guest, as this one seems to be less strict (and more raw).

Comment: I was in the same directory.

Comment: fFrom Ansible view?

Comment: Yes, i verified it, just like you suggested, and got the same directory.

Comment: See my edited answer - redirection will simply not work.

Comment: Shell module solved the problem:

    `shell: cat ./inet_licence_5 >> ./stage`